# Start Glances server automatically upon boot

Tags: boot, server, monitoring

Kinda new to Linux and trying to run a modest home server with Ubuntu 20.04. I've got an old monitor plugged in and would like it to serve as a way of monitoring activity.

Installed latest version of Glances (open to trying other local monitoring solutions if you have some).

I'm trying to get it to launch upon system boot so it launches Glances directly but can't find how. When it boots I'm prompted to log in. Access to root user is disabled.

I tried :

- adding `@reboot glances` with `sudo crontab -e`
- editing `/etc/rc.local` by adding :

```
#!/bin/bash
glances
exit 0
```

and running `sudo chmod a+x /etc/rc.local`

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Any service requiring a display must be started AFTER login, because no display server exists until then. Only headless services can be started before login. One possible workaround: The `cockpit` package creates a webpage instead of a local display, and can be monitored from anywhere on your network.

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate. I can access the service via ssh but I'd like the monitor to run this by default. Is there a way to disable login and launch the service ? With a good firewall protection would this still be as bad as it sounds security wise ?

Comment: Monitoring is easy. Monitoring applications are easy. A local monitoring display without login is possible but NOT easy. I recommend a few easier projects first, then circle back to the automatic-login display.

Comment: Understood, thank you for your answers.

Comment: @user535733 I did it ! I wasn't THAT hard, I just needed to be pointed in the right direction. Why did you make it sound that hard ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found the answer based on several other answers. The user used here has an empty password and limited abilities but I will not cover that part. For the rest here is what you need to do:

Make folder to override default login prompt for tty1:

```
#mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d
```

Copy the original tty configuration to edit it

```
#cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
```

Edit what will happen when boot process ends

```
#nano /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
```

Now replace the line starting with "ExecStart=" by these (replace userX with yours):

```
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a userX --noclear %I $TERM
```

Now add the software to launch after login

```
#nano /home/userX/.profile
```

Add this at the end:

```
if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then
   exec glances
fi
```

DONE ! Upon boot, user is logged and glances is launched on the screen ! Hooray